# Can you use a .NET 4.0 dll in a 3.5 project?

Tags: .net

Can you use a .NET 4.0 dll in a 3.5 project?

Comment: Is anything ever forward-compatible?

Comment: You can if you don't mind creating a COM wrapper/adapter and calling the .NET 4 DLL through that http://stackoverflow.com/a/9508452/74585

Comment: Please check my other answer to the same question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038442/how-can-i-use-net-4-0-code-in-c-sharp-project-which-is-built-using-net-framewo/16040309#16040309

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Nope.  You can use a .Net 3.5 assembly in a 4.0 project, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 17):

No you can't. An assembly compiled against .NET 4.0 can be loaded only by the CLR 4.0. On the other hand the CLR 4.0 can load assemblies compiled against .NET 3.5.

Comment: CLR 4.0 loading a 3.5 assembly surprised and confused me the other day.  Scratched my head over that one for a bit.

Comment: @Jim, why? If this wasn't possible I cannot even imagine ever migrating to .NET 4.0. Microsoft have always done a good job at keeping backwards compatibility when releasing new versions of the framework/CLR.

Comment: I don't know why it surprised me.  In retrospect, it shouldn't have.  But for some reason at the time I didn't expect it.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-a-NET-4-Based-DLL-bb141db3/

**Use our .NET 4 DLL via COM**

```
using System; 
using Net4ToNet2Adapter; 

namespace Net2Assembly 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("CLR version from EXE: {0}", Environment.Version); 
            Type myClassAdapterType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Net4ToNet2Adapter.MyClassAdapter"); 
            object myClassAdapterInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myClassAdapterType); 
            IMyClassAdapter myClassAdapter = (IMyClassAdapter)myClassAdapterInstance; 
            myClassAdapter.DoNet4Action(); 
        } 
    } 

}
```

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? I haven't tested it yet, but I will tomorrow.