# can .NET 4.5 dll work in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, ssis

I have created DLL (class library) in .NET FRAMEWIORK 4.5.

Now this dll will be use into SSIS VISUAL STUDIO 2008 SCRIPT FILE.

Can this be work ? or i need to create this dll in older version of framework ?

Thanks
Dhaval Soni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only SSIS 2014 has the ability to use 4.5 assemblies. You can only use 3.5 assemblies for SSIS 2008 (R2).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use .net 4.5 in Visual Studio 2008 just from vs 2012 or higher.
Source http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/488224/Usingplus-Netplus-pluswithplusVS

Comment: I mean for DLL. can i use .NET 4.5 dll into 3.5?

Comment: @Dhaval Please edit your question or make another one:D

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791078/can-you-use-a-net-4-0-dll-in-a-3-5-project