# how to integrate .net library (.dll) from higher version with binaries from lower version

Tags: .net, frameworks, external

I have external .net library compiled with .net framework 4 (it's provider moved recently to .net 4)
My code currently runs on .net framework 3.5
How to use that external library in my application ?
Moving whole application to .net 4 needs time and testing, so maybe in a future i will do that, but now, what are the possibilities ?

Answer (score 4):

There are no possibilities, the CLR version that comes with .NET 3.5 cannot load 4.0 assemblies.  The metadata format was changed.  You *have* to force your app to use the .NET 4.0 CLR version.  Do so by recompiling it with VS2010, targeting 4.0, or by using a .config file that contains the `<requestedRuntime>` element to ask for "v4.0".

Compatibility for .NET 4.0 is excellent btw.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot load the .Net DLL directly, you can wrap it in a COM interface, and load that COM interface in your .Net 3.5 process.

See [Using a .NET 4 Based DLL From a .NET 2 Based Application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-a-NET-4-Based-DLL-bb141db3)

For more background information, Microsoft originally added [In-Process Side-by-Side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx) in .Net 4 to better support the scenario where an application loads add-ins via COM, and the add-ins were written with various versions of .Net. The ability to load .Net 4 DLLs in a .Net 3.5 process is just a nice side effect of that.