# Accessing the .Net 4.0 Com from .Net 1.1 Project

Tags: dll, .net-4.0, com-interop, .net-1.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to integrate .net library (.dll) from higher version (.net 4) with binaries from lower version (.net 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377219/how-to-integrate-net-library-dll-from-higher-version-net-4-with-binaries)

I got an old .Net 1.1 dll that i converted it to .Net 4.0. And it will be used by old .Net 1.1 code using CreateObject("dll.className"). I registered the classes using regasm and i can see the classes in the registry.But the .Net 1.1 program not able to create the object. I tried to convert the consuming program to 4.0 and checked to see whether it can create the object. It works fine if both are 4.0. My question is is there any thing i need to do in 4.0 code so that 1.1 project can see the classes.