# The most stable way of making .Net 3.5 application talk to .Net 4.0 application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, t4

I have an application called NinjaTrader that uses .Net 3.5.  I have a Strategy that will send order information to a .dll written in .Net 3.5.  I need to send this order information to a platform called T4 that currently uses .Net 4.0.  I thought about using C++ as my .dll however everything still seems to target "some" .Net assembly.  I am currently using a asynchronous client server connection that does a decent job.  I just think it would be better to just run it through a .dll or something.  Does anybody have any ideas of the most stable solution?

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761640/making-a-call-to-a-net-4-library-from-3-5

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on using .NET from C++ you would need to use C++/CLI.

Also, in order to use CLR v4 you would need your project to run in .NET 4.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761640/making-a-call-to-a-net-4-library-from-3-5).

The best solution IMO would be to just recompile your project to target .NET 4. There shouldn't be many changes to make in your project assuming it's not a huge project. Have you tried recompiling for .NET 4?

Comment: yes actually I was able to first compile the dll in 3.5 and then add a reference in the project using 4.0.  Then I need to separately compile the project using 4.0 and it builds fine.  If I try to build the entire project it gives an error.  thanks :-)

Comment: Interesting, @SpencerDavis have you looked into the error or started another topic?